# Not enough information to infer parameter T

Tags: kotlin

`Context`: I am building a REST API with kotlin using Spring
`Problem`: I have a Kotlin class called `Response` that accepts a generic like this:

```
class Response<T> {

    var data: T? = null
    var dataArray: List<T>? = null
    var errors: List<String>? = null
        get() {
            if (field == null) {
                this.errors = ArrayList()
            }
            return field
        }
}
```

**When I try to instantiate in one of my `API Controllers` like this:**

```
val response = Response()
response.setData(someting)
```

It gives me `Not enough information to infer parameter T`.

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will have to specify what `T` is in this case. Supposing it is a `String`, you could do it like this:

```
val response = Response<String>()
response.data = "Something that is a String"
```